# WSO2 Call Template Mediator how to get a variable

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to use Call Template Mediator in WSO2 and I'm trying to get a dynamic value inside  function, but I don't find the way to get it.
For example:

```
<property expression="$ctx:variable" name="test" type="STRING"/>
<call-template target="HelloWorld_Logger">
<with-param name="message" value="VARIABLE: " expression="$ctx:test" />
</call-template>
```

I'm not able to get the property "test", if i remove `value` field the IDE reports an error.
There is some way to get a property inside `<call-template>` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Call Template Mediator doesn't have a parameter called `expression` to pass dynamic values. You must pass the XPath expression within `{}` to the `value` parameter itself. In your case, the call-template will be as follows,

```xml
<call-template target="HelloWorld_Logger">
    <with-param name="message" value="{$ctx:test}"/>
</call-template>
```

Please refer to the [Call Template Mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/call-Template-Mediator/#syntax) for more information.